# Summation of Functional equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

***Let $ f(k)$= $\dfrac{k}{2009}$ and $g(k)$ =$\dfrac{f^4(k)}{(1-f(k))^4+(f(k))^4}$ then the sum of 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2009} g(k)\
$$ is equal to***

My Approach : I substituted the values of $f(k)$ in $g(k)$ and formed the series . 
And I saw that the series was repeating after $1004$ , so I did twice. But still I cannot get any perfect answer.

The series is $$
\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\frac{k^4}{(2009-k)^4+k^4}  
$$

So it repeats after 1004 but I am not able to proceed ..

Please help...

Comment: Are you sure you wrote that correctly? Because $(1 - f^4(k)) + f^4(k) = 1$.

Comment: I made the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let 
$$ M_1=\sum_{k=0}^{2009}g(k)=\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\frac{k^4}{(2009-k)^4+k^4}, M_2=\sum_{k=0}^{2009}\frac{(2009-k)^4}{(2009-k)^4+k^4}. $$
Clearly $M_1=M_2$ by letting $n=2009-k$. Note $M_1+M_2=2010$ and hence $M_1=1005$.